# style a div to have the same background color after scrolling

Tags: android, html, css

My Android phonegap application has one scrollable div as below:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content" id="mContent" >
```

**CSS**

```
div#home{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height:100%;    
}

div#mContent{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    min-height:100%;    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My problem is that the background color (only on some device) is present only for the height which is initially displayed but when I scroll the rest gets black.

I tried with all the solution proposed in this similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704817/how-to-style-a-div-to-have-a-background-color-for-the-entire-width-of-the-conten) (in my case, using min-height)
but noone of them helped.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I am not very sure that this is not related to cordova, as I have'nt tried in another context

Comment: Try setting div#mContent to have a height of 100% as well as having the min-height

Comment: @Robert, thanks but there are no changes unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was

```
div#mContent {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

and

```
<div data-role="content" id="mContent " class="mContent" style="overflow:auto;">
```